# Is a Bb Baritone and a Baritone Horn the same instrument?

Tags: brass

I'm about to start A level music and therefore I need to buy an instrument, I play Bb baritone but when I searched for one on the internet all I could find was a baritone horn.

Is this the same instrument or different?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's the same. The baritone horn is typically just called a baritone and it is a Bb instrument so it's the same as the calling it a Bb baritone. Here is the basic description from [Wikipeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baritone_horn#Range):

> The baritone is part of the tenor section of a band. Its second
>   partial with no valves pressed is **concert B♭** on the second line from
>   the bottom of the bass clef (B♭2 in scientific pitch notation)

The baritone horn is a Bb instrument so it's exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The Bb baritone is actually an instrument group, consisting out of the baritone horn, tenor tuba and euphonium.
now, the differences between these are mostly academic, and composers use the names interchangably (although wrongly so).

In short: yes, the baritone horn is (most likely) what you are looking for. Just make sure that you get a compensated, 4-valve version, you'll be kicking yourself later if you don't